# MongoDB compass - NaN literal results in error?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I'm using MongoDB aggregation to sum some records. One of them has a `NaN` value and as such, the final value becomes `NaN`. I've written a `$project` step to convert `NaN` to `0`. However, using a `NaN` literal results in an error `Expected "[" or AggregationStage but "{" found.`

This `$project` step produces the error:

```
{
  "hardwareItems": 1,
  "subscriptionItems": 1,
  "sellerName": 1,
  "status": 1,
  "sum": {
    $cond: [{ $eq: ["sum", NaN] }, 0, "$sum"]
  },
  "seller": 1,
  "subscriptionCount": {
    "$size": "$subscriptionItems"
  }
}
```

However, if instead using:

```
$cond: [{ $eq: ["sum", "NaN"] }, 0, "$sum"]
```

Where `NaN` becomes `"NaN"`, the error goes away.

How would we use `NaN` literals in MongoDB Compass?

Comment: The statement is an error in "syntax", and not the `NaN` itself which is perfectly legal. `{ $eq: ["sum", NaN] }` is actually comparing the "string" of `"sum"` to be equal to `NaN`, which is **always** `false`. You probably mean `{ $eq: [ "$sum", NaN ] }` which is the *"field path epression"* to a property named `sum` within your document. I would not advise using that name for a property in general, since at the very least it's easily confused with `$sum` which is an aggregation operator, and probably used by an earlier stage of your aggregation pipeline.

Comment: BTW the **error** is produced by unbalanced `{}` and `[]` symbols. Easy to do, but a `NaN` ( which is perfectly legal JavaScript ) **will not** produce that error. Works just fine here, so your "typo" was actually somewhere else.